# C# AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument for Selenium 4.0.0-alpha04

Tags: c#, selenium

I use `Selenium 4.0.0-alpha04` for `C#`

I'm trying to inject `JavaScript` code that runs before a page loads

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
            DevToolsSession session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
            session.Page.AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.Page.AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocumentCommandSettings()
            {
                Source = @"Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', { get: () => undefined })"
            }
            );
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com") ;
        }
```

But it doesn't work, How can I fix it?

Comment: Please explain *it doesn't work*?

Comment: this JavaScript code is not executing

Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })

Comment: What did you expect to happen? what are you trying to do?